# Comparing variable with a string doesn't work

Tags: php

So I'm trying to compare a variable to a string, I even echo out the variable to make sure that it is the same as the string I'm comparing it to, but it won't work.

```
    $output = str_replace(',', '<br />', $row['order_summary']);
    $firstBreak = strpos($output, '<br />');
    $firstWord = explode(' ',trim($output))[0];         
    if ($firstWord == 'first' || $firstWord == 'second') {
        $output = str_replace(',', '<br />', $row['order_summary']);
        $firstBreak = strpos($output, '<br />');
        if($firstBreak === false) {
            $output = "<b>$output</b>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            $output = '<b>' . substr($output, 0, $firstBreak) . '</b>' . substr($output, $firstBreak);
        }
        echo $output;
    }
    else
    {
        $output = str_replace('.', '<br /><br>', $row['order_summary']);
        $firstBreak = strpos($output, '<br />');
        $output = '<b>' . substr($output, 0, $firstBreak) . '</b>' . substr($output, $firstBreak);
        echo $output;
    }
```

`$firstWord` when I echo it out, gives me `first` as a result, so it should obviously go through the if statement, instead it goes to the else statement.

Comment: @Sorry, I fixed the question, I meant `$firstWord`

Comment: Don’t use echo, use `var_dump` - that also shows you the length of the variable content, makes it easier to spot issues with extra white space.

Comment: @misorude Ok I used it, and it gives me `string(15) "first`.What should I do? I only want the `first` part of the string

Comment: Just trim it …?

Comment: use var_dump($firstWord) and compare output as manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have given simply given variable `$output=first;` 
Then the code is getting inside the if loop. 
So the problem is with the  `$output` variable.

```
<?php

$output = 'first';
$firstBreak = strpos($output, '<br />');
$firstWord = explode(' ', trim($output))[0];
if ($firstWord == 'first' || $firstWord == 'second') {
    echo 'test';
    exit;
    $output = str_replace(',', '<br />', $row['order_summary']);
    $firstBreak = strpos($output, '<br />');
    if ($firstBreak === false) {
        $output = "<b>$output</b>";
    } else {
        $output = '<b>' . substr($output, 0, $firstBreak) . '</b>' . substr($output, $firstBreak);
    }
    echo $output;
} else {
    $output = str_replace('.', '<br /><br>', $row['order_summary']);
    $firstBreak = strpos($output, '<br />');
    $output = '<b>' . substr($output, 0, $firstBreak) . '</b>' . substr($output, $firstBreak);
    echo $output;
}
```